# php $_POST variable variables

Tags: php, variables, post

I am trying to populate an HTML form with values from a previous form being posted. The first form is created dynamically and is a list of t-shirt styles with 5 different sizes available.

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to populate the second form.

The HTML is this:

```
echo '<input name="'.$filename.'-s" type="text" size="3" value="'.$quantity.'"'>;
```

What I'd like to do for $quantity is something like this:

```
$quantity = $_POST['{$filename.$size}'];
```

Is it possible to use a variable with $_POST?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? You don't even need quotes, just do: `$_POST[$filename . $size]` and try it

Comment: Single quoted strings are not parsed. Either use double quotes or no quotes as @Rizier123 advised

Comment: Please read this post, it is only a few days older than yours and the question is almost identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329499/php-post-of-input-that-has-a-variable-name/ (edit, this may not be an exact duplicate, but does solve the issue of parsing unknown array keys into `$_POST` )

Comment: where is the value `$size` coming from?

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks. I had tried that first and it didn't seem to work. Must have been something else. Got interrupted by a fire call in the middle of working on it and lost my place. So then I started trying all kinds of different variations. Got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
$quantity = htmlentities($_POST["$filename$size"]);
```

`htmlentities()` is necessary in case you have `"` or other junk in the input

Comment: I would add a small qualifier for the OP and recommend that `htmlentities` is used with as many of the variables filled in as possible, for example `htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", FALSE);` rather than relay on defaults.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST[$var1.$var2] worked. Nothing came up in my initial search of previous answers, although I see several applicable questions in the related questions on this page.